# Run-time error '13' can't find a solution to the problem

Tags: mismatch

I'm fairly new to VBA but it is necessary for the formula to not be in the cells since multiple people are going to use it. I've written an if-then code but it seems something is wrong and I can't figure it out. I've been looking around and I can't seem to find a solution. I get the error 13 type mismatch error on the Page = "Page: 1/5".

```
Sub Pagecontrole()

Dim Page As String
Page = Range("N4").Value

If Sheets("Lttlog P5").Range("F8:F37").Value = Not ("") Then
    Page = "Page: 1/5"
    Else
    If Sheets("Lttlog P4").Range("F8:F37").Value = Not ("") Then
        Page = "Page: 1/4"
        Else
        If Sheets("Lttlog P3").Range("F8:F37").Value = Not ("") Then
            Page = "Page: 1/3"
            Else
            If Sheets("Lttlog P2").Range("F8:F37").Value = Not ("") Then
            Page = "Page: 1/2"
            Else: Page = "Page: 1/1"
            End If
            End If
            End If
            End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is in the line before the one you indicate. `= Not ("")` doesn't seem to make sense - a range can't be an empty string, and can't be compared to one.

Comment: Ah i see. Thanks now i know where to look.

Comment: Fixed it now i get it :)  Thank you!